# Vue 3 router - router-link-active not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

In vue 3 with router 4 the class `router-link-active` isn't working anymore for me. The class appears if u are on the same page, together with `router-link-exact-active`, but not on any subpages.

For example the link `<router-link :to="{ name: 'test'}">test</router-link>` get's the classes `router-link-active` and `router-link-exact-active` on **/test** but none of them on **/test/2**

```
{
    path: '/test',
    name: 'test',
    component: Test
},
{
    path: '/test/2',
    name: 'test-2',
    component: Test2
},
```

Real Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-4-reproduction-forked-zcb7y

Thx, for any ideas or suggestions

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I missed https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#unrelated-but-similiar-routes, it's a bit hidden. The shown RouterView workaround works fine. Here's it for my example:

```
import { h } from 'vue'
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/test',
    component: { render: () => h(RouterView) },
    children: [
      { 
        path: '',
        name: 'test',
        component: Test
      },
      { 
        path: '2',
        name: 'test-2',
        component: Test2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy, thanks for the link

Comment: You are a godsend! I already implemented a dirty workaround myself, updating all links from an extended beforeEnter-function, but this is of course way better!

Comment: From the doc "It's worth noting, it is possible to nest them to still benefit from links being active...", well, it actually worth a lot in my case as I can't just nest the subpage as they are in the master-details relationship and the details can't be nested under the master list layout. This forces quite a lot of changes and requires to add an abstraction to the route hierarchy in many places. Frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem here and it turned out to be caused by having the route declared twice in the routing file AND the `<router-link>` was using the second declaration in the routing file, so the `active` prop was not working when you clicked the link but it did work if you reloaded the page while on it.

This was true because when you reload the page, the correct route was matched due to vue-router loading the first matching route.

After I changed the router-link to use the correct route AND deleted the duplicate route.

My situation was a bit strange because it somehow worked, there was little evidence in the code until I started logging `useRoute().name` onto the screen and I noticed it had a different/incorrect name.

As a bonus, the article that was linked in the other answer was helpful in confirming everything was working as expected: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#unrelated-but-similiar-routes