# Show nested URL as active in vue-router, when not a child view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, design-patterns, vue-router

I have a sidebar navigation with a "Projects" option in. In my vue-router I have the following routes defined.

```
/projects
/projects/:project_id
```

For `/project` this loads a list of all projects, and the `/projects/:project_id` should show details for a single project only. In each case, the UI fills the space, there are no shared behaviours/templating between them.

I want the "Projects" option in the sidebar to show as active, even when a user is at `/projects/:project_id`.

What are my options here? I am avoiding a nested child view as I don't want/need shared behaviour between them.

Comment: [This documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#unrelated-but-similiar-routes) get's me close, but only enables the rendering of the child components, not the parent as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Paul Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7244554/paul-tsai) for making me realise this was a Vue 3 specific problem. Realising this helped narrow down my searching, and then I found this:

[Vue 3 router - router-link-active not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375247/vue-3-router-router-link-active-not-working)

Which has a working solution linked, as `router-link-active` is no longer calculated from the URL, but from the hierarchy defined in the Router itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need router-link-exact-active

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#router-link-exact-active

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-forked-ocxxbl?file=/src/components/Navigation.vue

Comment: This doesn't make a `/projects` link active when at `/projects/project_id` though?

Comment: @JoePavitt please check out the example

Comment: Thanks @Paul Tsai, that works great, although needed a minor tweak which I added [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-forked-vtr11n?file=/src/components/Navigation.vue) to show how router-link-active is what I was needing. I should have specified though, I'm working in Vue 3 (and vue-router 4.0) and this doesn't appear to work there